# SQL Wrong output with select?

Tags: sql, select, output

I made an database with two tables. First is PERSON and second is REFEREES.

This is the code:

```
CREATE TABLE Person(
PersonID serial,
CONSTRAINT PK_Person PRIMARY KEY(PersonID),
FirstName VARCHAR(20),
LastName VARCHAR(30));

CREATE TABLE Referees(
RefereePairID SERIAL,
CONSTRAINT PK_Referee PRIMARY KEY(RefereePairID),
Referee1ID int,
Referee2ID int);

ALTER TABLE Referees
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Referee1 FOREIGN KEY(Referee1ID) references Person(PersonID);

ALTER TABLE Referees
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Referee2 FOREIGN KEY(Referee1ID) references Person(PersonID);

INSERT INTO Person VALUES (DEFAULT, 'AAAAAA', 'AAAAAA');
INSERT INTO Person VALUES (DEFAULT, 'BBBBBB', 'BBBBBB');  
INSERT INTO Person VALUES (DEFAULT, 'CCCCCC', 'CCCCCC');  
INSERT INTO Person VALUES (DEFAULT, 'DDDDDD', 'DDDDDD');  

INSERT INTO Referees VALUES (DEFAULT, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO Referees VALUES (DEFAULT, 3, 4);
```

Output from next query I expected to be:

```
SELECT * FROM Person, Referees WHERE Referees.RefereePairID = 1;

PersonID |FirstName|LastName|RefereePairID|Referee1ID|Referee2ID
---------+---------+--------+-------------+----------+----------
       1 | AAAAAA  | AAAAAA |      1      |     1    |     2
       2 | BBBBBB  | BBBBBB |      1      |     1    |     2
```

But, the problem is that the output is this:

```
PersonID |FirstName|LastName|RefereePairID|Referee1ID|Referee2ID
---------+---------+--------+-------------+----------+----------
       1 | AAAAAA  | AAAAAA |      1      |     1    |     2
       2 | BBBBBB  | BBBBBB |      1      |     1    |     2
       3 | CCCCCC  | CCCCCC |      1      |     1    |     2
       4 | DDDDDD  | DDDDDD |      1      |     1    |     2
```

Also, when I type next query I get these result:

```
SELECT * FROM Referees WHERE Referees.RefereePairID = 1;

 RefereePairID | Referee1ID | Referee2ID
---------------+------------+------------
             1 |          1 |          2
```

Can anybody know where is the problem? Because I don't get it :(

Comment: You're creating a [`Cartesian product`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-cartesian-joins.htm).

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
SELECT *  
FROM Person, Referees
```

what happens is a **cartesian product** between the tables. This is the same as

```
SELECT * 
FROM Person CROSS JOIN Referees;
```

And you get:

```
+----------+-----------+----------+---------------+------------+------------+
| PersonID | FirstName | LastName | RefereePairID | Referee1ID | Referee2ID |
+----------+-----------+----------+---------------+------------+------------+
|        1 | AAAAAA    | AAAAAA   |             1 |          1 |          2 |
|        1 | AAAAAA    | AAAAAA   |             2 |          3 |          4 |
|        2 | BBBBBB    | BBBBBB   |             1 |          1 |          2 |
|        2 | BBBBBB    | BBBBBB   |             2 |          3 |          4 |
|        3 | CCCCCC    | CCCCCC   |             1 |          1 |          2 |
|        3 | CCCCCC    | CCCCCC   |             2 |          3 |          4 |
|        4 | DDDDDD    | DDDDDD   |             1 |          1 |          2 |
|        4 | DDDDDD    | DDDDDD   |             2 |          3 |          4 |
+----------+-----------+----------+---------------+------------+------------+
```

You need to add an extra condition like this

```
SELECT *   
FROM Person, Referees 
WHERE Referees.RefereePairID = 1 
  AND (Referees.Referee1ID = Person.PersonId OR Referees.Referee2ID = Person.PersonId);
```

to get the expected result

```
+----------+-----------+----------+---------------+------------+------------+
| PersonID | FirstName | LastName | RefereePairID | Referee1ID | Referee2ID |
+----------+-----------+----------+---------------+------------+------------+
|        1 | AAAAAA    | AAAAAA   |             1 |          1 |          2 |
|        2 | BBBBBB    | BBBBBB   |             1 |          1 |          2 |
+----------+-----------+----------+---------------+------------+------------+
```

But like some people mentioned here, there's a proper way to do queries like these. You should be using a JOIN clause:

```
SELECT *   
FROM Person
JOIN Referees
ON (Referees.Referee1ID = Person.PersonId OR Referees.Referee2ID = Person.PersonId)
WHERE Referees.RefereePairID = 1
```

Maybe Wikipedia can help with some concepts:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your FK definition, and also in the SQL.

**Here's a working SQLFiddle** that fixes both these issues and returns the dataset you are expecting: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b7141/1

Your 2nd Foreign Key Definition also refers to `RefereeID1` instead of `RefereeID2`.

So modify that definition like so

```
ALTER TABLE Referees
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Referee2 FOREIGN KEY(Referee2ID) references Person(PersonID);
```

Also, your SQL is incorrect. Here's the right SQL.

```
SELECT * FROM Person 
    JOIN Referees 
        ON Person.PersonID = Referees.Referee1ID 
            OR Person.PersonID = Referees.Referee2ID 
    WHERE Referees.RefereePairID = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first statement, I guess You wanted to join tables based on their relation, so the query should rather look similar to this:

```
SELECT * FROM Person 
    JOIN Referees 
        ON Person.PersonID = Referees.Referee1ID 
            OR Person.PersonID = Referees.Referee2ID 
    WHERE Referees.RefereePairID = 1
```

If, for some reason, You don't want to use `JOIN`, You can pass those additional matching conditions to `WHERE`:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM Person, Referees 
    WHERE (Person.PersonID = Referees.Referee1ID OR Person.PersonID = Referees.Referee2ID) 
        AND Referees.RefereePairID = 1
```

***The thing is, You have to write in Your SQL statement how You want to match the records between tables. You've defined foreign keys, but they won't provide You with automatic matching when selecting from multiple tables in Your SQL statements.***

I haven't tested those SQL statements, so they can contain errors.

Additionally, as mentioned in another answer, You should also correct one of the constraints.

Comment: Yes, it is, You're right, but the most important part of this issue seems to be joining records from multiple tables.